# Pros and cons of load specific view to mobile devices

Tags: php, codeigniter, mobile, media-queries, user-agent

I'm using Codeigniter, and I've noticed using the [User agent library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html) we can know if the user device to know if is a mobile or not. And based on this, we can load one or another view with the same url. Something like this:

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
$data = array (
     //some data
);
if (!$this->agent->is_mobile()) {
     $this->load->view('test_view',$data);
}
else {
    $this->load->view('test_view_mobile',$data);
}
```

Well, it works perfectly, and using this:

- We dont have to put css media-queries. Just put the mobile css in the corespondient view.
- We don't have to track exceptions for mobile user such as touch events or similar.
- We can load small images than desktop devices. Becouse the screen size is smaller.

These are the pros that I realiced. But what about the cons? Is there any problematic or issue using this practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are reasons not to use it - even if the library works perfectly - new devices come out all the time. And if the device is not recognized - then they are getting the full screen version.

And even if you have a team of people and every device is recognized - **you are creating two different content resources for the same page**. This means that as your content and resources change - you have to change it in two different places. And there are search engine issues with this.

All of these issues are why front end responsive libraries are so popular - they take care of these issues AND make your site content work better on tablets.  Twitter Bootstrap is by far the most popular. http://getbootstrap.com https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

note that if you go to learn more about twitter bootstrap there are breaking changes between bootstrap 2 and bootstrap 3 (latest version)

Answer (score -1):

Cons are: The documentation sucks.

- For me as a CodeIgniter novice, it's unclear what `$this` refers to.
- What exactly is a *mobile device*?
- Which mobile devices are *known*?
- What argument must I pass to the function to test for a particular mobile device?
- I've seen `'iphone'` has been passed to the function in the example. Does that include *all* iPhones or just the ones that where available at the time that the function was written?
- What characteristics can I assume about the client when the function returns `true`?